# Unable to overwrite init value of a function once set by monkeypatch for singleton class

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I have a very simple python class with a constructor:

```
from utils.util import Singleton
class VaultAuth(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
    def __init__(self, prefix_path, address):     

        self.path = prefix_path
        self.vault_url = address            
        self.is_authenticated = False

    def get_secrets(self, region):         
        print self.is_authenticated 
        if not self.is_authenticated:
            raise RuntimeError("Failed to fetch secrets")
        else:
            return True
```

where Singleton class looks as follows:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

To write unit tests I have:

```
@pytest.mark.unit_test
def test_get_secrets(monkeypatch):
    def mock_init_auth_false(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.path = "dummy_path"
        self.vault_url = "dummy_url"
        self.is_authenticated = False

    def mock_init_auth_true(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.path = "dummy_path"
        self.vault_url = "dummy_url"
        self.is_authenticated = True

    # Negative case - auth is false
    monkeypatch.setattr(vault1.VaultAuth, "__init__", mock_init_auth_false)
    secrets_manager = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")
    with pytest.raises(RuntimeError) as exception:
        secret_data = secrets_manager.get_secrets(region="test_region")
    assert "Failed to fetch secrets" in str(exception.value)
    monkeypatch.undo()

    # Positive case - auth is true
    monkeypatch.setattr(vault1.VaultAuth, "__init__", mock_init_auth_true)
    secrets_manager = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")
    assert secrets_manager.get_secrets(region="test_region")
```

The first test print is_authenticated value as False as per expectation but the second test also prints it as False. If I reverse the order of the tests both print `True`. Any pointers? The class is singleton. How to test a singleton class function?

Comment: Your code isn't runnable per se; if I fix syntax errors and raise the correct error type, the test runs as expected (prints `False` then `True`, then pass) so the issue isn't reproducible.

Comment: I edited the code to fix syntax errors. And the class is singleton. That's the reason the object did not change. How to destroy the object for the test?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply deleting the singleton instance before the second test case?

```py
@pytest.mark.unit_test
def test_get_secrets(monkeypatch):
    def mock_init_auth_false(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.path = "dummy_path"
        self.vault_url = "dummy_url"
        self.is_authenticated = False

    def mock_init_auth_true(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.path = "dummy_path"
        self.vault_url = "dummy_url"
        self.is_authenticated = True

    # Negative case - auth is false
    monkeypatch.setattr(vault1.VaultAuth, "__init__", mock_init_auth_false)
    secrets_manager = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")
    with pytest.raises(RuntimeError) as exception:
        secret_data = secrets_manager.get_secrets(region="test_region")
    assert "Failed to fetch secrets" in str(exception.value)
    monkeypatch.undo()

    del Singleton._instances[vault1.VaultAuth]

    # Positive case - auth is true
    monkeypatch.setattr(vault1.VaultAuth, "__init__", mock_init_auth_true)
    secrets_manager = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")
    assert secrets_manager.get_secrets(region="test_region")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using a `Singleton` pattern, so there is just *one* instance of the class and the `__init__` method is not going to be called twice here.

Since you are unit-testing the `get_secrets()` method, just adjust the state of the singleton instance for the test:

```
@pytest.mark.unit_test
def test_get_secrets():
    secrets_manager = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")

    # Negative case - auth is false
    secrets_manager.is_authenticated = False
    with pytest.raises(RuntimeError) as exception:
        secret_data = secrets_manager.get_secrets(region="test_region")
    assert "Failed to fetch secrets" in str(exception.value)

    # Positive case - auth is true
    secrets_manager.is_authenticated = True
    assert secrets_manager.get_secrets(region="test_region")
```

*However*, there can easily be other issues with the above test, because the Singleton class is created *for the lifetime of your Python process*. If other tests use `vault1.VaultAuth(...)` anywhere with different arguments, you'll have an issue with those tests because they are given the same singleton instance.

You certainly could use with an escape hatch method for your singleton class, to use in your tests; the `Singleton._clear_singleton()` method will remove the cached instance for a given class, simply by calling `ClassObject._clear_singleton()`:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

    def _clear_singleton(cls):
        # remove the singleton instance for this class (if it exists)
        cls._instances.pop(cls, None)
```

so you can *at least* clear out the existing singleton instance:

```
# clear singleton cache for VaultAuth before creating test instance:
vault1.VaultAuth._clear_singleton()

try:
    # use vault1.VaultAuth in a test
    secrets_manager = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")
    # ...
finally:
    vault1.VaultAuth._clear_singleton()

try:
    # ... more tests
    secrets_manager = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")
finally:
    vault1.VaultAuth._clear_singleton()
```

The `try: ... finally:` pattern ensures that the singleton created for the tests is at least cleaned up. You can make this a pytest fixture too:

```
@pytest.fixture
def vaultauth():
    """The vault1.VaultAuth class, without the singleton cache"""
    vault1.VaultAuth._clear_singleton()
    try:
        yield vault1.VaultAuth
    finally:
        vault1.VaultAuth._clear_singleton()
```

but this would only clear out the singleton per test function, not multiple times during the test itself.

However, rather than mocking `__init__` you could just *subclass* the class, as you are then using separate classes. These each are cached as singletons separately:

```
@pytest.mark.unit_test
def test_get_secrets():
    # Negative case - auth is false
    class VaultAuthNotAuthenticated(vault1.VaultAuth):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.is_authenticated = False

    secrets_manager = VaultAuthNotAuthenticated(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")
    with pytest.raises(RuntimeError) as exception:
        secret_data = secrets_manager.get_secrets(region="test_region")
    assert "Failed to fetch secrets" in str(exception.value)

    # Positive case - auth is true
    class VaultAuthNotAuthenticated(vault1.VaultAuth):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.is_authenticated = True

    secrets_manager = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="prefix", address="https://vault")
    assert secrets_manager.get_secrets(region="test_region")
```

**However**, given that the class takes specific parameters (prefix, address), it looks as if you are using the wrong pattern here.

You probably wanted to cache the instances *based on the arguments*, so a single instance per `(prefix_path, address)` pair:

```
class VaultAuth(object):
    _vaults = {}

    def __new__(cls, prefix_path, address):
        key = (prefix_path, address)
        if key not in cls._vaults:
            cls._vaults[key] = self = super(cls, VaultAuth).__new__(cls)
            self.prefix_path = prefix_path
            self.address = address
            self.is_authenticated = False
        return cls._vaults[key]
```

This creates a single instance for each unique combination of prefix and address. Note that it doesn't have an `__init__` method! I did so deliberately, you can use one but it will be called on *any instance of `VaultAuth` or a subclass thereof* if returned from `__new__`, even if that instance was created before and just returned from the `cls._vaults` mapping.

At any rate, you can then use this in tests by just using made-up arguments, and altering the attributes to suit your test:

```
@pytest.mark.unit_test
def test_get_secrets():
    # Negative case - auth is false
    not_authenticated = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="not_authenticated", address="https://foo")
    not_authenticated.is_authenticated = False
    with pytest.raises(RuntimeError) as exception:
        secret_data = not_authenticated.get_secrets(region="test_region")
    assert "Failed to fetch secrets" in str(exception.value)

    # Positive case - auth is true
    authenticated = vault1.VaultAuth(prefix_path="authenticated", address="https://bar")
    authenticated.is_authenticated = True
    assert authenticated.get_secrets(region="test_region")
```

By using test-specific arguments, the instances created are far less likely to interfere with other tests, and you can have separate vaults for different addresses.